# Reading system.net/mailSettings/smtp from Web.config in Medium trust environment

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-3.5

I have some inherited code which stores SMTP server, username, password in the `system.net/mailSettings/smtp` section of the Web.config.

It used to read them like so:

```
Configuration c = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath);
MailSettingsSectionGroup settings = (MailSettingsSectionGroup)c.GetSectionGroup("system.net/mailSettings");
return settings.Smtp.Network.Host;
```

But this was failing when I had to deploy to a medium trust environment.

So following the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927343/asp-net-security-exception-with-openwebconfiguration-on-shared-host), I rewrote it to use `GetSection()` like so:

```
SmtpSection settings = (SmtpSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.net/mailSettings/smtp");
return settings.Network.Host;
```

But it's still giving me a SecurityException on Medium trust, with the following message:

> Request for ConfigurationPermission
>   failed while attempting to access
>   configuration section
>   'system.net/mailSettings/smtp'. To
>   allow all callers to access the data
>   for this section, set section
>   attribute 'requirePermission' equal
>   'false' in the configuration file
>   where this section is declared.

So I tried this `requirePermission` attribute, but can't figure out where to put it.

If I apply it to the <smtp> node, I get a ConfigurationError: "Unrecognized attribute 'requirePermission'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive."

If I apply it to the <mailSettings> node, I still get the SecurityException.

Is there any way to get at this config section programatically under medium trust? Or should I just give up on it and move the setting into <appSettings>?

Comment: Whenever I had that setting I didn't need to "read it". Just creating a new SmtpClient() would use the settings on the web.config.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The requirePemission attribute goes on the `<configSections>` grouping that matches the part fo the web.config you are having the security issue with.

additionally, you don't have to actually read the settings using code to send mail - you can simply use a blank SmtpClient:

```
 new SmtpClient.Send(MyMailMessage);
```

it will send using the settings from the config sections by default.

Comment: Heh, just using `new SmtpClient()` rather than trying to manually extract the host and port and username and password works perfectly!

Answer (score 26):

You can create a SmtpClient as some suggested, but that is a bit overkill - just read the sections directly.

```
var section = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.net/mailSettings/smtp") as SmtpSection;
var host=section.Network.Host
```

Comment: I've followed this whole process, but getting null values all time? What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

This works very well to me.

```
var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
var host = smtp.Host;
var ssl = smtp.EnableSsl;
var port = smtp.Port;

var credential = new System.Net.Configuration.SmtpSection().Network;
var username = credential.UserName;
var password = credential.Password;
```

Answer (score 2):

Joys of coding eh... always 1000 ways to skin a fish

```
System.Net.Configuration.SmtpSection smtp = new System.Net.Configuration.SmtpSection();
string from = smtp.From;
//etc
System.Net.Configuration.SmtpNetworkElement nt = new System.Net.Configuration.SmtpNetworkElement();
string host = nt.Host;
//etc
```

Comment: This just returns `null` - it doesn't appear to reflect what you have in your Web.config...

Comment: Does not work.  That just creates the elements, does not read them.

Answer (score 2):

To get the settings from the mail sections just create the mail objects.

```
var client = new SmtpClient();
var messageSettings = new MailMessage();

var host=client.Host;
//etc...

var fromAddress=messageSettings.From.Address;
//etc..
```

Config:

```
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="xxxx@yahoo.com" deliveryMethod="Network" >
        <network host="smtp.mail.yahoo.com" port="587" enableSsl="true"
            userName="xxxx@yahoo.com" password="xxxxxxx"/>
      </smtp>     
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```