# Read from Web.config file for FromEmail address

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, web-config

I want to get the SMTP from address from my `Web.config`, I am not sure how to do this below is my code from `Web.config` file.

```
system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="yourmail@gmail.com">
```

In my controller, I want to read the `Web.config` data, how do I do this?

I used the code below but it didn't work.

```
var fromAddress = new MailAddress("from@gmail.com", "From Name"); //Add from email from web config file
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate Question You can see the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11945231)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add Email address to your web.config

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="FromEmail" value="yourmail@gmail.com" />
  </appSettings>
```

And get it in a controller:

```
 string Email = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FromEmail"];
```

**Edit:**
OP has mailSettings in config file:

```
    <system.net> 
      <mailSettings> 
        <smtp from="yourmail@gmail.com"> <!--EMAIL FROM MAYANK--> 
          <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" userName="yourmail@gmail.com" password="yourpassword" enableSsl="true"/>   </smtp> 
  </mailSettings> 
 </system.net>
```

In that case you can use like this:

```
var msgSettings = new MailMessage();

var Email = msgSettings.From.Address;
```

Comment: <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="yourmail@gmail.com"> <!--EMAIL FROM MAYANK-->
        <network host="smtp.gmail.com"
         port="587"
         userName="yourmail@gmail.com"
         password="yourpassword"
         enableSsl="true"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>

Answer (score 0):

Config your smtp in code

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 465);
smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxxx@gmail.com", "***");
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.Send(mail);
```